# Compiler says I'm not conforming to UICollectionViewDelegate; conflicts with Actual Use

Tags: swift, xcode6, uicollectionviewdelegate

I believe I'm following the UICollectionViewDataSource, but the compiler says otherwise.

What am I missing?

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class InviteFriendsViewController:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func navButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: AnyObject = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("InviteFriendsVC", forIndexPath:indexPath)
        return cell as UICollectionViewCell
    }
}
```

[image]

I have two (2) func that covers the required APIs... but I'm getting this compiler error.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your functions like this way:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return 1
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let cell: AnyObject = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("InviteFriendsVC", forIndexPath:indexPath)
    return cell as UICollectionViewCell
}
```

Try this may be it can help you.

Comment: Yes. You did it.
Thanks!